# Ormlite : Execute 2 stored procedures in one go with out parameter

Tags: c#, ssis, ormlite-servicestack

I need to run following sql from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/ssis-quickstart-run-tsql-vscode?view=sql-server-ver15

it executes 2 stored procedures with one out parameter

```
Declare @execution_id bigint
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[create_execution] @package_name=N'Package.dtsx',
    @execution_id=@execution_id OUTPUT,
    @folder_name=N'Deployed Projects',
      @project_name=N'Integration Services Project1',
    @use32bitruntime=False,
      @reference_id=Null
Select @execution_id
DECLARE @var0 smallint = 1
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] @execution_id,
    @object_type=50,
      @parameter_name=N'LOGGING_LEVEL',
      @parameter_value=@var0
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[start_execution] @execution_id
GO
```

I want to run it using ormlite as its already used in project. I tried using  db.ExecuteSql() as it contains executing 2 stored procedures and first using seconds output as input but I don't understand how to get the out parameter (execution_id) value back?  or is there any other way to do it using ormlite only.

```
db.ExecuteSql(@"Declare @execution_id bigint
    EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[create_execution] @package_name=N'Package.dtsx',
        @execution_id=@execution_id OUTPUT,
        @folder_name=N'Deployed Projects',
          @project_name=N'Integration Services Project1',
        @use32bitruntime=False,
          @reference_id=Null
    Select @execution_id
    DECLARE @var0 smallint = 1
    EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] @execution_id,
        @object_type=50,
          @parameter_name=N'LOGGING_LEVEL',
          @parameter_value=@var0
    EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[start_execution] @execution_id
    GO")
```

How to get execution_id back?

Thanks.

Comment: There's some examples for executing Stored Procedures with out parameters in https://docs.servicestack.net/ormlite/stored-procedures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about ormlite but the documentation for "[Issuing raw Queries](https://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite.html#Raw-Queries)" looks like what you need. Also, does

There is no OUT parameter to be dealt with. The results of execution are a result set which has 1 row and 1 column, sometimes referenced as scalar results.

ORMLite which appears to be java based

```
// I am too lazy to lookup multi-line strings in Java
GenericRawResults<String[]> rawResults =
  orderDao.queryRaw(
    "Declare @execution_id bigint
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[create_execution] @package_name=N'Package.dtsx',
    @execution_id=@execution_id OUTPUT,
    @folder_name=N'Deployed Projects',
      @project_name=N'Integration Services Project1',
    @use32bitruntime=False,
      @reference_id=Null;
// This is what you're calling an OUT parameter but it's just a result set
Select @execution_id;

DECLARE @var0 smallint = 1;
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] @execution_id,
    @object_type=50,
      @parameter_name=N'LOGGING_LEVEL',
      @parameter_value=@var0
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[start_execution] @execution_id;");
// there should be 1 result
List<String[]> results = rawResults.getResults();
// the results array should have 1 value
String[] resultArray = results.get(0);
// this should print the number of orders that have this account-id
System.out.println("The execution_id is  " + resultArray[0]);
```

ormlite-servicestack is .NET product so there you're looking to run a query, the [Custom SQL](https://docs.servicestack.net/ormlite/custom-sql#custom-selects) documentation seems appropriate.

```
string query = @"Declare @execution_id bigint
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[create_execution] @package_name=N'Package.dtsx',
    @execution_id=@execution_id OUTPUT,
    @folder_name=N'Deployed Projects',
      @project_name=N'Integration Services Project1',
    @use32bitruntime=False,
      @reference_id=Null;
// This is what you're calling an OUT parameter but it's just a result set
Select @execution_id;

DECLARE @var0 smallint = 1;
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] @execution_id,
    @object_type=50,
      @parameter_name=N'LOGGING_LEVEL',
      @parameter_value=@var0
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[start_execution] @execution_id;";
// a bigint for the results
long executionId = 0l;

executionId = db.SqlScalar<long>(query);
```